# Targetting a link to load inside a DIV

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have created a menu which is simply a series of DIVs and am using the following code

```
$(".menu_item").click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");
return false;
});
```

to make the entire DIV for each item clickable. I have a "container" DIV setup with content initially loaded via php-include, but want different content to load when a different menu item is clicked.

I know I can use JQuery.load to target the loading of an external file into a sepcific DIV but it looks that would  mean coding separate instances of jquery for each link? I would also rather stick to using php includes if possible. Can I use jquery.load to load via php include?

Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Here's the rest of the code:

```
/* Menu Item */
<div class="menu_item" data-href="link1.html">
     Link 1
</div>

/* Container to load link into */         
<div id="myContentDiv"></div>
```

Comment: try $(this).find('a').attr('href'). Put an anchor in the div first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery AJAX shorthand method `load()` which makes the ajax request and on completion populates the element with response

```
$(".menu_item").click(function(e){
   var url= $(this).data('href')
    $('#myContentDiv').load( url);
     return false;/* edit to prevent browser following link*/
  });
```

API Reference:  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: How do I set the link? I had been using "data-href" inside the DIV tag but this appears to be different.

Comment: jQuery `data()` method reads the "data-href" . read section in API regarding HTML5 attribues  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/  See demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/mB4Ez/

Comment: Thanks. I have the link working but just not loading into the correct DIV. It's just printing the entire text file in the browser. I have double checked my target DIV name and it's as it should be.

Comment: "text file" sounds strange...  have a link can look at? Can see a lot about the AJAX in a browser console

Comment: What I mean is I uploaded a dummy .txt file to test whether it was pulling it into the page when the link was clicked. However the result was the same with a html file, the link just opened in the browser rather than loading it into the DIV. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: need to return `false` from click handler to prevent browser following link... see edit

Comment: Still not getting it to work. It must be something I am doing wrong. I've edited my first post with all of my code but I can't see what can be wrong.

Comment: post a link to live demo so can inspect it in browser console

Comment: you forgot to remove the redirect code :  `window.location = $(this).attr("data-href");` It fires before the other code

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".menu_item").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("data-href"),
      context: $('#div-to-replace-content')
    }).done(function(data){
      $(this).append(data);
    });
  });
```

Comment: I set the data-href target and the correct container DIV name, but that code is not opening the file in the container DIV.